# MVC4 how to disable System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView() cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I'm trying to disable the view engines findpartialview() / findview(), but there is no useCache parameter as in this [documentation site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iviewengine.findpartialview(v=vs.118).aspx) it is written that there is the third parameter that indicates the using of cache.

Is there a way to implement the findview with no caching?

I'm using System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.3.0 and runtime version v4.0.30319